# Automatically move incoming emails by subject to sub folder in a shared mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

We organize emails within a shared mailbox. There are folders for each area, then a sub folder for each specific location.

I am trying to check the subject line of incoming email to move the email to its proper folder.

The thing to look for in the subject line is similar to "%%-%%" the percents being letters. We have over 900 locations and I would like to not have to create 900 rules.

```
Sub MoveToFolder(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim Subject As String
    Subject = Item.Subject

    Dim FolderToMoveTo As Outlook.Folder
    Set FolderToMoveTo = GetFolder("KX-BH")

    If (CheckSubject(Subject, "KX-BH")) Then
        Item.Move (FolderToMoveTo)
    End If

End Sub


Function CheckSubject(Subject As String, PatternToCheck As String)

    Dim ObjRegExp As RegExp
    Dim ObjMatch As Match

    Set ObjRegExp = New RegExp
    ObjRegExp.Pattern = PatternToCheck

    If (ObjRegExp.Text(Subject) = True) Then
        CheckSubject = True
    End If

End Function


Function GetFolder(ByVal FolderName As String) As Outlook.Folder

    Dim ObjFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set ObjFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(FolderName)
    Set GetFolder = ObjFolder

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are interested in the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

```
Public WithEvents outApp As Outlook.Application

Sub Intialize_Handler()
    Set outApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub outApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
   Dim mai As Outlook.MailItem
   Set mai = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strEntryId)

   MsgBox mai.Subject

   MoveToFolder(mai)
End Sub
```